# jQuery AJAX stops user from being able to change page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple ajax going through in an `each` statement:

```
$('.product').each(function () {
      var product = $(this).attr('data-product');
      $.ajax({
          url:"/ajax/product",
          data:"lookup=" + product,
          success: function () { /* callback */ }
      });
});
```

There are 5 products currently in the `each` loop.

My problem is that the user cannot press the form `submit` button until all of these ajax lookups have completed; the ajax call takes some time to process each time due to it calling an external API. More specifically, they can press the `submit` button but it does not do anything until all of the ajax functions appear to have completed.

How can I make the ajax calls volatile / not wait for a reply if the user wants to submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `setTimeout()` which will make the call to happen on a different thread.

```
$('.product').each(function() {
      setTimeout(function () {
         var product = $(this).attr('data-product');
         $.ajax({
            url:"/ajax/product",
            data:"lookup=" + product,
            success: function () { /* callback */ }
         });
    });
});
```

[jQuery.deferred](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) allows similar feature where code is executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass a callback to your function, to process the data when it is ready:

```
myFunction: function(callback) {
    $.get(myUrl, function(data) {
        callback( data );
    });
}
```

OR you can try doing like this:

```
$('.product').each(function () {
      var product = $(this).attr('data-product');
      $.ajax({
          url:"/ajax/product",
          data:"lookup=" + product,
          async:true,
          success: function () { /* callback */ }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user can press the `submit` button anytime, and it'll do what it's supposed to do - which is submit everything inside the form.

The real thing you need to do is populate the form containing the submit button before/after initiating the AJAX requests, but not inside a callback.

This way the user can click the `submit` button anytime he/she wants.